# Deleted and Closed questions are no longer showing the close reason and votes

Tags: bug, deleted-questions, close-reasons

When viewing a deleted question that had currently been closed, the close reason(s) and the close voters are no longer displayed. It only shows the deletion action.

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/305827) (10k only), for instance, was closed before it was deleted, but the reasons for closing are not in evidence. That information is available in the [timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/305827/timeline), of course, but that's not easy for mortals to find.

Can the closing information be restored?